# How do I create a new line in TextBox whenever it starts a new row in C#?

Tags: c#, textbox, line, lines, string-length

I want to get a specific line from a text showed in a TextBox (could be RichTextBox as well, it doesn't really matter), but `TextBox.Lines` Method recognize a new line only if there was an "Enter" inside the text.

My text is continuous, but the TextBox drops a line at a time runs out place on the same line. Is it possible to get a specific row from the text box by its length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After wordwrap in a textbox, you can make use of this function:

```
textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
```